# how to update text on image created by canvas after interval of time

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I am working on mobile app in which i am creating image using canvas and then writing text on that image and i want to update that text after some interval of time.

I used:

`clearRect(0,0,canvas.height,canvas.width)`

to clear the text but it clear the whole canvas or when we use `clearRect` by giving co-ordinates it clear the text and the colour of image from that particular portion, but i want to clear the text or update the text not the background image.

Kindly suggest.

Thankx in advance

Comment: Just redraw your background, drawImage is fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different canvas for text and place it over the image canvas using CSS(**canvas is transparent**). This way, you can perform any operation on text without affecting image canvas.

or you can fix image in the background if you don't require canvas image

see solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432212/7549867

```js
var textcanvas= document.getElementById('text');
var ctx = textcanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",textcanvas.width/6, textcanvas.height/2); 

function changetext(text){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,textcanvas.width, textcanvas.height);
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillText(text,textcanvas.width/6, textcanvas.height/2);
}
```

```css
#img{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red
}

#text{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:fixed;
  left:60px;
  top:60px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="img"></canvas>
<canvas id="text"></canvas>
<button type="button" onclick="changetext('Text Changed!')">Change Text</button>
```

Comment: On using clearRect(), it remove text asa well as the circle below the text. But I want to remove the text only.

Answer (score 0):

Replace clearRect( ... )
with drawImage(image, dx, dy);

When the text is written on the canvas the image that was placed on the canvas becomes an image with the text, what is under the text is over written. Likewise when the image is written to the canvas, it overwrites what was there before. drawImage() does what you want clearRect() to do, leaves the canvas with the image but no text.

Alternately, If your canvas is more than an image or is otherwise changing:

Using two canvas elements a text canvas on top of a image canvas would make readability and programming simpler, (when you or someone else want to change things 6 months or a year from now). Example show with inline styling, you would of course want to move the inline styles to the style sheet.

```
<div id="canvasShell" style="position:relative;width:**EnterValue**;height:**EnterValue**">
<canvas id="ctxBackground" style="position:absolute"></canvas>
<canvas id="ctxText" style="position:absolute></canvas>
</div>
```

Note you must also have the correct value for the shell width and height, or the canvas elements will be placed on top of other content on the page.

Comment: I tried your solution, but on using two canvas, it is taking separate place for each canvas vertically. I want to place one canvas over another.Kindly suggest.

Comment: Sorry style both canvas elements to position:absolute; the first element is draw first the 2nd renders on top of it. The shell must be position:relative;

Comment: stacking of elements on top of each other can be done with just one of the canvases styled with position:absolute but that canvas would be drawn on top of the element not positioned, making readability hard ... and if the last canvas is position:absolute it will place it vertically below the other unless top:0px is also used.