# How to reset text on canvas in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, reset

I have created simple meme generator using canvas Bootstrap and some JavaScript. I am new to JavaScript and I know only basic stuff.

Now I am trying to make reset button that has function to reset text on canvas, I have tried with adding function to reset width but it is reseting the whole canvas, is there any solution for this.

The problem is that I want to reset only text not the whole canvas and image on canvas.

```js
$('#thumbs img').click(function() {
  $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
  $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});


var memeSize = 600;

var canvas = document.getElementById('memecanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


// Set the text style to that to which we are accustomed



canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

//  Grab the nodes
var img = document.getElementById('largeImage');
var topText = document.getElementById('inputdefault');
var bottomText = document.getElementById('inputdefault2');

// When the image has loaded...
img.onload = function() {
  drawMeme()
}

topText.addEventListener('keydown', drawMeme)
topText.addEventListener('keyup', drawMeme)
topText.addEventListener('change', drawMeme)

bottomText.addEventListener('keydown', drawMeme)
bottomText.addEventListener('keyup', drawMeme)
bottomText.addEventListener('change', drawMeme)

function drawMeme() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, memeSize, memeSize);

  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.font = '40pt impact';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';

  var text1 = document.getElementById('inputdefault').value;
  text1 = text1.toUpperCase();
  x = memeSize / 2;
  y = 0;

  wrapText(ctx, text1, x, y, 580, 60, false);

  ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
  var text2 = document.getElementById('inputdefault2').value;
  text2 = text2.toUpperCase();
  y = memeSize;

  wrapText(ctx, text2, x, y, 580, 60, true);

}

function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight, fromBottom) {

  var pushMethod = (fromBottom) ? 'unshift' : 'push';

  lineHeight = (fromBottom) ? -lineHeight : lineHeight;

  var lines = [];
  var y = y;
  var line = '';
  var words = text.split(' ');

  for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + ' ' + words[n];
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;

    if (testWidth > maxWidth) {
      lines[pushMethod](line);
      line = words[n] + ' ';
    } else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  lines[pushMethod](line);

  for (var k in lines) {
    context.strokeText(lines[k], x, y + lineHeight * k);
    context.fillText(lines[k], x, y + lineHeight * k);
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="memecanvas">
        <img id="largeImage" src="images/zlatko3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="1st image description" />
      </canvas>


</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault2" type="text">

    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Reset</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">SHARE ON FACEBOOK</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete only Text but not the Image using Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431332/delete-only-text-but-not-the-image-using-canvas)

Comment: Try using two canvases as layers, and erase the text from one canvas on reset.